# Background-position not working on an img class

Tags: css, image, background-position

I have an img in a container that is half of the containers height. The img is too big, so I'm using the object-fit property, however it's cutting the img off at the top. I'm using the following CSS and no matter what value I enter in the background-position property it doesn't do anything.

```html
.testbox img {
    position: relative;
    display: table-cell;
    width: 100%;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: bottom;
    overflow: hidden;
    height: 150px;
    -o-object-fit: cover;
    object-fit: cover;
```

Can anyone see anything wrong with what I'm doing? Any pointers would be really appreciated!

Thanks

Comment: Well `img` is not a _background_ image, so there is no reason `background-position` should have any effect on it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `background-position` property is only for background images
You could use the property `object-position` for your `img`.

https://css-tricks.com/on-object-fit-and-object-position/